# SWIG : convert item of a numpy array to a C++ typedef

Tags: numpy, typedef, swig

Here is a minimal example (ubuntu 18.04, swig 4.2.0):

**Var.hpp**

```
#include <iostream>

typedef int MY_INT;

void printMyInt(MY_INT v)
{
  std::cout << "MyInt is " << v << std::endl;
}
```

**var.i**

```
%module pyvar

%include Var.hpp

%{
  #include "Var.hpp"
%}
```

**test_var.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from pyvar import *
import numpy as np

v = 6
arr = [v]
nparr = np.array(arr)

printMyInt(v)         # OK
printMyInt(arr[0])    # OK
printMyInt(nparr[0])  # NOK
```

The last instruction produces the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fors/Projets/test/swig/cpp_python_npint64/test_var.py", line 12, in <module>
    printMyInt(nparr[0])  # NOK
  File "/home/fors/Projets/test/swig/cpp_python_npint64/pyvar.py", line 63, in printMyInt
    return _pyvar.printMyInt(v)
TypeError: in method 'printMyInt', argument 1 of type 'MY_INT'
```

Following this: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/swig.interface-file.html

- I tried to include `numpy.i` and `pyfragments.swg` to the project
- I tried `%apply` etc...

But nothing works!

What is the strict minimal thing to do please?

Answer (score 0):

`type(nparr[0])` is `numpy.int32` and SWIG expects a Python `int` type, so you can use `printMyInt(int(nparr[0]))` to convert the array element to a Python type SWIG understands.

Also, although I couldn't find documentation for it, I found on inspection of the generated code that defining `SWIG_PYTHON_CAST_MODE` will add an attempt to cast the parameter to `int` for you, so the following also works:

```cpp
%module test

%inline %{
#define SWIG_PYTHON_CAST_MODE
#include <iostream>

typedef int MY_INT;

void printMyInt(MY_INT v)
{
  std::cout << "MyInt is " << v << std::endl;
}
%}
```

Usage:

```
>>> from test import *
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.array([6])
>>> printMyInt(a[0])
MyInt is 6
```